# Is there an addon that helps me download all images of an being-viewed web page?

Tags: google-chrome, images, download

I search for this addon on the Google Chrome home page bu
Ut can not find one. If you know how to do this, please help.

Comment: According to the developers of DownThemAll, the tool which does exactly what you want for firefox, it's actually not possible due to how chrome does extensions.

Answer (score 1):

#### The [Picnik extention](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hcifofgaphfkfdcjbdogpamghiihilkl) for Google Chrome lets you capture web pages and edit images right in your browser.

> The Picnik Extension for Chrome lets you easily edit the images you come across while browsing the web. With a click you can create a snapshot of your current web page and open it in Picnik for easy editing, annotation and sharing.  Do the same for **all the image on the current page** -- just pick the image from the dynamic hot list and then edit, annotate and share with Picnik.

Comment: It's a great addon to edit 1 file :) I prefer a mass-downloader one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That extension is a screencap addon, not a mass-picture-downloader like Nam wants.